# Getting the name of functionally created enum.Enum class

Tags: python, enums

If I have a functionally created enum.Enum in python (3.7 in this case), how do I retrieve the name of the class from it?

```py
import enum

def print_the_enum_class_name(some_enum_class):
    print(...) # ?

my_enum_class = enum.Enum('FunctionallyCreatedEnum', 'RED GREEN BLUE')

print_the_enum_class_name(my_enum_class) # Should print FunctionallyCreatedEnum
```

This seems like it should be simple, but I can't find a suitable member in the docs, and hunting around in `.__dict__` and doing `dir(my_enum_class)` also don't seem to have the answer.

There are `_name_` sunders on each of the singletons (referred to as enumeration members by the docs) inside the Enum (e.g. `print(my_enum_class.RED._name_) # prints RED`, but there's no `_name_` on the class itself. There's also a plain `.name` that's the same.

It must be stored somewhere though, since

```
print(repr(my_enum_class)) # prints <enum 'FunctionallyCreatedEnum'>
```

Unfortunately

```
print(type(my_enum_class)) # prints enum.EnumMeta
print(my_enum_class.__class__.__name__) # also prints enum.EnumMeta
```

so it doesn't seem to be associated with the type as many of the similar questions about getting the type name in general in python suggest.

Comment: How about `my_enum_class.__name__`?

Comment: `__repr__` could have been created with its return value hard-coded; the name doesn't necessarily have to be otherwise accessible (though it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def print_the_enum_class_name(some_enum_class):
    print(some_enum_class.__name__)
```

:)

Comment: Well now I'm just dumb and I feel bad. But Imma leave this here since the docs don't supply it for any other lost souls!